# Define two variables with one sub and then use them in another

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to define two variables with one sub and then use them in another.

```
Dim A As Long
Dim B As Long

Sub checkparameters()
With ActiveChart.Parent
    MsgBox .Left & vbCrLf & .Top & vbCrLf & .Height & vbCrLf & .Width
    A = .Height
    B = .Width
End With
End Sub

Sub value()
MsgBox A & vbCrLf & B
End Sub
```

Sub value just shows null value.

NB: I tried setting A and B as Public variables and it still doesn't work.

Comment: basic debugging: did you actually call `checkparameters`? did you check what values are getting set in there?

Comment: Well, I put a MsgBox after the 'End With' if that's what you mean? and they are indeed being set correctly.

Comment: You do have an `Active` chart, yes?

Comment: Yep, I'm clicking a chart, and then running 'checkparameters' at the end of the End With it then displays a MsgBox with the correct Height and Width values stored. When I then call 'value' it displays a box with nothing inside it.

Comment: are the methods all in one Module?  are they in a sheet module?

Comment: Your code works for me as posted.  Somehow you're resetting the VB project between calling `checkparameters` and `value`.  Do you have other code running which might be doing that?  Also you say you get a messagebox with "nothing inside it" - at the very least it should contain 0 and 0.

Comment: Sorry for the delay and thanks for the response. All of the subs I've written on in one module (with a horizontal line separating each one). I don't have any code I'm aware of that is resetting it - which is what has caused confusion, in the past I always just set the parameter as Public and it worked. I can also confirm that the message box is just a blank box, it does not contain 0,0. Thanks again for any help.